# Highlighting search terms in mustache template

Tags: html, css, mustache

I have this simple mustache template for listing song titles:

```
<h1>{{#term}}Search: <i>{{.}}</i>{{/term}}{{^term}}Every song{{/term}}</h1>

<ul>
{{#songs}}
    <li><a href="song/{{id}}">{{title}}</a>
{{/songs}}
</ul>
```

Is there any good way to highlight instances of `term` in the `title` using mustache here? Or do I have to fix that before passing it to the template?

And by highlighting I mean to wrap instances of the text with a `<span>` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which mustache implementation you're using, you could use a lambda section to process your title (see "Lambdas" [on this page](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html)), but really, this is best done in preparing your view.